# libmtp-Fehler: Could not get file from device

Tags: qfield

When trying to transfer my project data back to my Ubuntu 20.x I get the error `"libmtp-Fehler:  Could not get file from device"`.
I already tried several things, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879029/libmtp-error-could-not-get-file-from-device-on-attempting-to-transfer-files) and others that I get from a Google search.

Is there any hint from your side towards this problem? I use QField 2.0.15 at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the QField private folder? that might be related, but I'm not sure.

Due to new google policies we, unfortunately, had to remove some storage access functionalities and use the QField private folder. This folder is only available to QField. the next QField version will have even better import/export functionality.

you can find many more details here: https://www.opengis.ch/qfield-storage

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested now another import/export option, described in your mentioned URL above and that works perfectly for me! Great!

Comment: great! maybe you could accept my answer as correct? cheers Marco